# Stoichiometry reactions for water clarification

Tags: stoichiometry, precipitation

If ferric chloride was added to a water sample which had calcium bicarbonate alkalinity present, would the reaction be a ‘stoichiometry reaction’ or a ‘limiting reagent reaction’?

For example, if 1 g of ferric chloride was added, how much precipitate would form [$\ce{Fe(OH)3}$] and what type of reaction (mentioned above) would happen?

$$\ce{2FeCl3(aq) + 3Ca(HCO3)2(aq) ->2Fe(OH)3(s) + 3CaCl2(aq) + 6CO2(g)}$$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! What have you tried so far? Perhaps thinking in terms of moles rather than grams would be helpful. If you have 2 moles of ferric chloride, what happens per your equation?

Comment: In order to determine the reaction is "stoichiometric" or has a limiting reactant, we need to know the volume and the concentration of the calcium bicarbonate solution.

Comment: @Ben Norris: Thanks for correcting my bad balancing!

Comment: our test was to see how much precipitate formed. we did not know how much calcium bicarbonate was in the reaction